# Customer can't login after Use SID on Frontend = No

Tags: magento-1.9, login, session

I am using **Magento 1.9.3** and `server` **Godaddy VPS**.
I am trying to `disable` `Use SID on Frontend` in `admin->configuration->web->Session Validation Settings->Use SID on Frontend` `No`.

After this change `URL` working properly but customers can't login in `front-end`. Even `invalid username and password` message also not displaying, just page loading.

But same function is working in `localhost`.

How can I fix this issues...?

And thanks in advance....

Comment: have customized any customer login section?

Comment: No am using default customer login @Abdul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the solution

**Solution 1:**

Go to **System->configuration->web->Session and Cookie Management**

[image]

Change **Cookie Domain** to your domain name(example.com).

Now clear you magento cache and also delete all cache of your chrome and try to login again.

**Solution 2:**
 If solution1 is not working for you, you can try this one. But make sure to revert changes you did in solution1.

Add following rules in your `.htaccess` file. To redirect Non `www` url to `www.`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to : `system->configuration->web->unsecure (and secure if needed)` and fill in http://www.domaine.com for the base url and base link url.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But sorry it's not working